# Language-dependent MP3 files increase the size of my Android application

Tags: android, optimization, size, mp3

I today released an Android application which includes some language-dependent MP3 files. My concern is that the more languages, the bigger the application size.

What would be your recommendation:

- Release one application per language (not really easy to deal with, would have to release n apps each time I add new features to the software)
- Provide a mechanism to download the MP3 files at first launch (would require an internet connection whereas the user may think he doesn't need one. It could bring frustration.)
- Optimize the MP3 files (not that scalable if I have to support 10 languages)
- [    ] fill the blank !

Hervé.

Comment: As a side note, there are better formats for speech compression. This would mean smaller files.

Comment: @CAFxX, which format would you recommend for Android 2.2 and up?

Comment: I'd say [speex](http://www.speex.org/) and [opus](http://www.opus-codec.org/) are good candidates. You'll probably need to link the relevant libraries, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big fan of user-choice. As such, I might make the MP3 files optional, but on first run explain to the user that you have some language-dependant features and allow them to download them if they desire.

The reasons for this are many:

1. It keeps the file size low.
2. It is easily supportable with one distribution.
3. It allows you to extend/correct the language files independent of the software.
4. It is upfront, and gives the user the choice of language (even potentially multiple).
5. It allows the user to change the aural language without having to uninstall/reinstall or have duplicate installs.
6. There are many users (such as myself) who never speak to their phone, and never want to hear it speak to them. :) (Yes, I'm crazy)

Just a suggestion!

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Another unnecessary perk: for those learning new language, they could have different written language combined with different spoken language.

Comment: Thanks for your logical/pragmatic suggestion. For your information, I added audio files to enhance the learning experience (my app teaches multiplication and addition tables). It is possible to enable/disable audio from the app preferences.

Comment: You're very welcome. In this case, I would find it hard to completely separate the MP3s from the app. I would instead utilize a default language with an optional separate MP3 only download for other languages. An option to change the language could start the download and this would be understandable. This would still retain all of the benefits above, but also insure that nobody goes without. (Spoken tongue is so important for learning!)